# create surface math with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a basic surface z=square_root(x^2+2*y^2) using only geometry nodes like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeKkf.jpg

I don't know to which type of mesh I should apply this geometry nodes.

In my opinion, I have to add a vector as input in the geometry nodes but nothing is drawn for me

Can someone help me?

thanks

I don't understand why this nodes configuration doesn't give me another desired function z=square_root(4-x^2-y^2)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could just generate a Mesh Primitive > *Grid*, and set its point-positions to (**x**,**y**,**f(x,y)**):

[image]

[image]